# Django Rest Framework pagination not working

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

These are my version

```
Django==3.0.2
djangorestframework==3.11.0
```

and this is my setting

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
        'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
            'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
        ],
        'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.LimitOffsetPagination',
        'PAGE_SIZE': 10
    }
```

and this is my views:

```
class CostList(ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = CostSerializers

    def get_queryset(self):
        cost = Cost.objects.filter(
            id='filtered with one of my id'
        )
        return cost
```

this is my serializer:

```
class CostSerializers(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Cost
        fields = '__all__'
```

Everything is working fine but the only issue is pagination. I have 100+ entry in `cost` model and I see it is rendering all the entry together, not paginating item following my settings

Comment: Try adding the `def paginate_queryset(self, queryset)` method in your `CostList` view (just calling `super()`) and set a breakpoint there. Inspect the value of `self.paginator`. There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your code.

Comment: Try this => https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class CostList(ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = CostSerializers

    def get_queryset(self):
        cost = Cost.objects.filter(id='filtered with one of my id')
        return cost

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = self.get_queryset()
        page = self.paginate_queryset(qs)
        return self.get_paginated_response(page)
```

Try this.